# Is there a way to print a stack trace to screen in Java ME?

Tags: exception, java-me, mobile

I have code that looks like the following, which works fine for displaying the message, but can't figure out any way to get a hold of the stack trace.

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException("This is bad stuff!");
} catch (Exception e ) {
    mainForm.append("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Calling e.printStackTrace() sends it somewhere that I can't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this article:
http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/12/redirecting-output-on-s60-devices.html

too bad there is no System.setErr(PrintWriter) or Thread.getStackTrace()

I don't think there is a (generic) solution for this problem

Comment: This is totally awesome!  I happened to be using an S60 device, so this was perfect

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Stack trace is always printed to System.err and there is no way in CLDC to redirect System.err to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Even in CLDC 1.1 this does not exist.. hope Sun includes redirection of error and out stream in future versions. It is very essential of logging/debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool that can be used to log proper stack traces also in CLDC. Check it out at http://jarrut.sourceforge.net. It's still very new and it might have some rough edges, but it works for me and I couldn't imagine developing MIDlets without it anymore. Best way to use it is to combine it with microlog.